# Calculate how much has been donated from total spent in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

So I'm working on a website where the owner donates a certain percentage of every order to a charity.

At the bottom of the user's account page is a section that shows the customer how much donations has been made from all of their orders.

So essentially the customer has spent £100 total across all orders and each order has had a 2% donation.

How would I do this using Liquid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% assign total = customer.tota_spent %} <!-- if total spent is 100 -->
{% assign percent = 2 %} <!-- and the donation percent is 2 -->
<!-- total divided by 100 would be 1 percent, times by 2 for 2 percent. -->
{% assign donation = total | divided_by: 100 | times: percent %}

{{ donation }}<!-- outputs 2 if the total spent is 100 -->
```

Comment: [This is a helpful resource](https://www.shopify.com.au/partners/shopify-cheat-sheet) if you want to know what information you have access to.

Comment: Oh yeah, I use that regularly. My problem is my math knowledge is dreadful so I don't know how to calculate it. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sum total price of all orders.. Remove decimals.. Divide by 50..

Links to help you..

1. https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/order
2. https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/money-filters
3. https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/math-filters